# Adding macros in a CSV file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a CSV file where I need to add a macro to insert the current date. I know you can't add a macro into a CSV so I stored it in a separate macro enabled .xlsm file. However when I try to run the macro I get a "Subscript out of range" error. How can I make this work?

Here is the code that is run:

```
Sub Insert_StartDate()
'
' Insert_StartDate Macro
' Inserts the current date into the StartDate fields
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("J2").Select
    Windows("Activity File (White Collar 1).csv").Activate
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J2:J13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you possibly add some relevant macro code to your question (so we might see *which* subscript is out of range)?

Comment: Yup, just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Insert_StartDate()

    With Workbooks("Activity File (White Collar 1).csv").Sheets(1).Range("J2:J13")
        .Value = Date
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!